# Index optimizations for redundant data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm storing the same `tags: ['hello', 'world']` in multiple documents which is indexed.

Does it make sense to use an external mapping: `tags: { hello: 1, world: 2 }` which is resolved on the client in favor of reduced index space and size of tags on disk?

Essentially, a client side compression with the mapping pulled from a static config file.

Comment: what does the numbers 1 and 2 refer to? The mapping maps what to what? is tags the index key or part of it?

Comment: They don't refer to anything. I just thought it might take up less space to store integers rather than potentially long strings, in multiple documents.

Comment: I also have a similar problem deciding on how to store one-to-many references with respect to minimizing index space. Should the "one" `_id` be stored in multiple documents with an index on the "one" field or should I store the "many" _ids within the "one" thereby removing the need for an index in the latter situation since I'm querying for the "many" documents by the "one" _id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storage space is a concern, then using as small field names and values whenever possible possible is an advantage. As you surmised this will reduce the amount of data stored on disk. Assuming your client can handle the mapping long term (and you can handle maintenance of the mappings) I cannot see any disadvantages.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering, are data types referenced when more than one field contains the same value like referencing a pointer to the primitive value in a software program?

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, yes. All of the MongoDB BSON fields are stored as C++ primitives of varying types at the lowest level, even within an Index. You can look at the implementation of the low level BSON within the source code https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/bson

Comment: But does that translate to indexes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942338/do-indexes-utilize-pointers

Comment: Yes. Take the following portion of the MongoDB codebase https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/structure/btree/btreebuilder.cpp

Has functions which build indexes and allows the adding of keys, which are BSONObj's that are defined in the bson code from earlier

Comment: So, in conclusion, is it encouraged/ok to store human addressable text names directly in multiple documents instead of having to refer to any static mapping between the text and an integer? I just want to make sure that I can apply this to single-key indexes as well as multi-key.

Comment: Encouraged? No, this decision would 100% depend on use case. Acceptable? Yes. If you are able to maintain a mapping, then using lower overhead datatypes can be an advantage, especially if you have a larger number of values to index.

Comment: I mean, is it ok to store `tags: ['hello 'world']` in multiple documents? The initial alternative I was contemplating involved keeping a static json map along with the app code `{ 'hello': 1, 'world', 2 }` and then storing the integer in the database.

Comment: Yes. It is okay to store something like tags: ['hello 'world'] in each document that has tags. It is also acceptable to store tags:[1, 2] in each document, then have a client side mapping which translates the 1,2 into 'hello' and 'world'

Comment: Which is the "better way" in terms of long-term performance though? I suppose if I were to have a `text` index on it then there's no choice though.

Comment: Performance differences on tags of the size we have bee discussing should be negligible. There would be some extra overhead in performing a string comparison to performing an integer comparison, but ideally there would be a number of other factors you could change before this was your performance bottleneck. And yes, if you wish to use text search you would need to use the string values.