# Do indexes utilize pointers?

Tags: mongodb

How are mongodb indexes stored in RAM? For example, if there are documents like:

`{ fruit: 'apple', tags: ['hello', 'world', 'rainbow' ] }`

`{ fruit: 'banana', tags: ['hello', 'world', 'unicorn' ] }`

`{ fruit: 'orange', tags: ['hello', 'world', 'lion' ] }`

With an index on the `tags` field. Will the `'hello'` and `'world'` tags be stored in a single memory location and then have pointers reference them within the indexes? Or does a new `String` get instantiated for every tag?

Comment: This is a rather untrue format of an index however, I would imagine that every document in the index is in fact a memory address unto itself and the contents of the document are stored unqiuely in that address, as such it would replicate the string value across the addresses where it is duplicated

Comment: I forgot to add that the tags field is indexed in this case and let's assume covered queries are the only ones executed on this collection. Although it would be nice to have this apply for entire documents loaded in memory for uncovered queries.

Comment: It is still a bad representation, think of indexes are more like buckets of values with document pointers, each value in an array would be indexed separately, as said below. This changes the perspective a little. However, it also changes my thoghts on the subject since the document pointer is the repeated part and I believe that uses "pointer"s instead of duplicated memory addresses

Answer (score 0):

From the [`documentation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/):

> To index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB adds index items for each item in the array.

So, separate entries are created for each array element.

Comment: Yes, but does it reference a single value in memory? If not that would be a severe optimization oversight.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot answer that question, as I'm not familiar with the internal implementation details.  I would trust the smart engineers at MongoDB :)